# Array with counted items of a other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array, in this array will be saved a JavaScript object.

```
var items = [];

var item = {
   id: data.id,
   kategorie: data.kategorie,
   name: data.name
}

items.push(item);        // that will be done few times
```

Now i have items like this

```
items[0] = id: 1, kategorie: "scheduled", name: "Test1"
items[1] = id: 2, kategorie: "queued", name: "Test2"
items[2] = id: 3, kategorie: "recorded", name: "Test3"
items[3] = id: 4, kategorie: "recorded", name: "Test4" 
items[4] = id: 5, kategorie: "recorded", name: "Test5"
```

I wanna count this array. At least the final array should be like this.

```
arrayFinal[0] = kategorie: "scheduled", counted: 1
arrayFinal[1] = kategorie: "recorded", counted: 3
```

How I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into underscore.js's `_.countBy` routine:

```
counts = _.countBy(items, "kategorie");
```

That will create an object looking like this:

```
{ 
    recorded : 3,
    ...
}
```

To convert that into the array format, you want `_.map`:

```
arrayFinal = _.map(counts, function(v,k){
    return {kategorie: k, counted: v};
});
```

There, you're done.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't produce your exact output, but it gives you an idea of what to do:

```
var items = [],
    arrayFinal = [];

items[0] = {
    id: 1,
    kategorie: "scheduled",
    name: "Test1"
};
items[1] = {
    id: 2,
    kategorie: "queued",
    name: "Test2"
};
items[2] = {
    id: 3,
    kategorie: "recorded",
    name: "Test3"
};
items[3] = {
    id: 4,
    kategorie: "recorded",
    name: "Test4"
};
items[4] = {
    id: 5,
    kategorie: "recorded",
    name: "Test5"
};

items.forEach(function (v, i) {
    if (typeof arrayFinal[v.kategorie] === 'undefined') {
        arrayFinal[v.kategorie] = 1;
    } else {
        arrayFinal[v.kategorie] += 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with linq you can write a query. Group by kategorie, count IDs.

[LINQ for JavaScript](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/)

Eg.:

```
 var queryResult = Enumerable.From(items)    
.GroupBy("$.kategorie", "", 'key,e=>key+":"+e.Count()', "").ToJSON();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = [
    { id: 1, kategorie: "scheduled", name: "Test1" },
    { id: 2, kategorie: "queued", name: "Test2" },
    { id: 3, kategorie: "recorded", name: "Test3" },
    { id: 4, kategorie: "recorded", name: "Test4" },
    { id: 5, kategorie: "recorded", name: "Test5" }
];

var index, 
    arrayFinal = [];
arrayFinal.contains = function(kategorie) {
    for(var i = 0, len = arrayFinal.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(arrayFinal[i].kategorie === kategorie) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

for(var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    if( index = arrayFinal.contains(items[i].kategorie)) {
        arrayFinal[index].counted++;
    } else {
       arrayFinal.push({ kategorie: items[i].kategorie, counted: 1 });
    }
}
```

Comment: it returns me all my items with counted 1

Comment: I just tried it in the console with the `items` array you provided and `"recorded"` has 3 in counted. I'll add the items array so you can check it too.

Answer (score 0):

If you thought a bit and experiment, you'd do it.

1. Create an associative array `kategorieCount`.
2. Iterate over `items`. If there is `kategorieCount[items[i].name]` increment it, if not – create the element at `i` and then increment value.
3. Create an array `arrayFinal`.
4. Iterate over `kategorieCount`. Put the key in `arrayFinal[i].kategorie` and the value in `arrayFinal[i].counted`.